# NSUserdefaults not working with NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I have a NSMutableArray filled with objects of my Movie class wich i want to save but it doesn't work and i can not figure out why...

Movie.h:

```
@interface Movie : NSObject <NSCoding>{
    NSString *name;
    int year;
    int length;
    NSString *file_size;
    int rating;
    NSArray *genre;
    NSString *plot;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int year;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int length;
@property (nonatomic, retain, retain) NSString *file_size;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *genre;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *plot;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString*)newName year:(int)newYear length:(int)newLength filesize:(NSString*)newFileSize rating:(int)newRating genre:(NSArray*)newGenre plot:(NSString*)newPlot;
- (void) encodeWithCoder : (NSCoder *)encode ;
- (id) initWithCoder : (NSCoder *)decode;

@end
```

Movie.m:

```
@implementation Movie

@synthesize name;
@synthesize year;
@synthesize length;
@synthesize file_size;
@synthesize rating;
@synthesize genre;
@synthesize plot;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)newName year:(int)newYear length:(int)newLength filesize:(NSString *)newFileSize rating:(int)newRating genre:(NSArray *)newGenre plot:(NSString *)newPlot{
    self.name = newName;
    self.year = newYear;
    self.length = newLength;
    self.file_size = newFileSize;
    self.rating = newRating;
    self.genre = newGenre;
    self.plot = newPlot;
    return self;
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encode;
{
    [encode encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [encode encodeInt32:year forKey:@"year"];
    [encode encodeInt32:length forKey:@"length"];
    [encode encodeObject:file_size forKey:@"file_size"];
    [encode encodeInt32:rating forKey:@"rating"];
    [encode encodeObject:genre forKey:@"genre"];
    [encode encodeObject:plot forKey:@"plot"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decode;
{
        NSString *name_decode = [decode decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        int year_decode = [decode decodeInt32ForKey:@"year"];
        int length_decode = [decode decodeInt32ForKey:@"length"];
    NSString *file_size_decode = [decode decodeObjectForKey:@"file_size"];
    int rating_decode = [decode decodeInt32ForKey:@"rating"];
    NSArray *genre_decode = [decode decodeObjectForKey:@"genre"];
    NSString *plot_decode =[decode decodeObjectForKey:@"plot"];
    return [self initWithName:name_decode year:year_decode length:length_decode filesize:file_size_decode rating:rating_decode genre:genre_decode plot:plot_decode];
}

@end
```

Save Action (Movies is the NSMutableArray containing my Objects):

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:Movies];
    [userDefault setObject:encodedData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MOVIES"]];
```

Load Action:

```
NSData *decodedData = [userDefault objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MOVIES"]];
    NSArray *decodedArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedData];
```

The returned Array is always (null)... i have no clue
I tried several different kind of code snippets i found on the internet and/or stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Movie initWithName...` method is incorrect. It needs to be:

```
- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)newName year:(int)newYear length:(int)newLength filesize:(NSString *)newFileSize rating:(int)newRating genre:(NSArray *)newGenre plot:(NSString *)newPlot {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = newName;
        self.year = newYear;
        self.length = newLength;
        self.file_size = newFileSize;
        self.rating = newRating;
        self.genre = newGenre;
        self.plot = newPlot;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Also, you seem to be following a very out-of-date tutorial.

1. You don't need to declare the ivars for your properties.
2. You don't need the calls to `@synthesize`.
3. You should be using ARC instead of MRC, Therefore your `retain` properties should be `strong` (thought the `NSString` properties should be `copy`.
4. Your `init` methods should return `instancetype`, not `id`.

With all of that in mind, your `Movie` class should be as follows:

**Movie.h**

```
@interface Movie : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int year;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int length;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *file_size;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rating;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *genre;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *plot;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)newName year:(int)newYear length:(int)newLength filesize:(NSString *)newFileSize rating:(int)newRating genre:(NSArray *)newGenre plot:(NSString *)newPlot;

@end
```

**Movie.m**

```
@implementation Movie

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)newName year:(int)newYear length:(int)newLength filesize:(NSString *)newFileSize rating:(int)newRating genre:(NSArray *)newGenre plot:(NSString *)newPlot {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = newName;
        _year = newYear;
        _length = newLength;
        _file_size = newFileSize;
        _rating = newRating;
        _genre = newGenre;
        _plot = newPlot;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encode;
{
    [encode encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encode encodeInt32:self.year forKey:@"year"];
    [encode encodeInt32:self.length forKey:@"length"];
    [encode encodeObject:self.file_size forKey:@"file_size"];
    [encode encodeInt32:self.rating forKey:@"rating"];
    [encode encodeObject:self.genre forKey:@"genre"];
    [encode encodeObject:self.plot forKey:@"plot"];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decode;
{
    NSString *name_decode = [decode decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    int year_decode = [decode decodeInt32ForKey:@"year"];
    int length_decode = [decode decodeInt32ForKey:@"length"];
    NSString *file_size_decode = [decode decodeObjectForKey:@"file_size"];
    int rating_decode = [decode decodeInt32ForKey:@"rating"];
    NSArray *genre_decode = [decode decodeObjectForKey:@"genre"];
    NSString *plot_decode =[decode decodeObjectForKey:@"plot"];
    return [self initWithName:name_decode year:year_decode length:length_decode filesize:file_size_decode rating:rating_decode genre:genre_decode plot:plot_decode];
}

@end
```

You don't show how you create and populate your `Movies` variable (which should be named `movies`, not `Movies`. Make sure it isn't `nil`.

Also, don't needlessly use `stringWithFormat`.

Your saving code should be:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:movies];
[userDefault setObject:encodedData forKey:@"MOVIES"];
```

and your loading code should be:

```
NSData *decodedData = [userDefault objectForKey:@"MOVIES"];
NSArray *decodedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedData];
```

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy! that did it for me! :))
BTW, Movies was not the problem, it must have been the decode/encode selector

Answer (score 0):

A quick test is to see if the mutable array is actually not nil itself. Try outputting the mutable array before setting it in `userDefaults`.

Make sure the mutable array is initialized before trying to add objects to it.

```
movies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```